# Regular Expression for anything enclosed in double squar bracket

Tags: php, regex, string

I have been trying to extract some strings or any kinds of values which are enclosed in double squar bracket. i.e. `[[hello world]]` or `[[12_ nine]]` etc. That's mean anything but which are enclosed in two squar bracket. Please check this [URL](http://regexr.com/3b10m), where I tried. However, I am explaining below what I did:

```
/\[[^\]]*\]]/
```

This pattern can validate anything inside `[[]]`. My problem is, it validate also `[]]`. I am giving two examples what this parttern validate `[[Welcome]]` `[v2.0]]`. I need second example should not be validated. See the [URL](http://regexr.com/3b10m), you can understand better.

Comment: You need to escape `[` and `]` using `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: @OhAuth: the closing square bracket is not a special character and doesn't need to be escaped except in a character class when it is not at the first position or immediatly after the `^`

Comment: Do you want to allow square brackets in the middle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
/\[\[[^\]]*\]\]/
```

Here's how it's defined:

- First two (escaped) brackets: `\[\[`
- Then something that's not brackets: `[^\]]*`
- Then two closing brackets: `\]\]` (you could keep them unescaped too, it's a matter of style)

Note that it won't match strings having square brackets in the middle (e.g. `[[ A [B] C]]`). If you want to allow those strings, use

```
/\[\[.*?\]\]/
```

If that must be the whole string, as seems to be from your comment below, use

```
/^\[\[.*?\]\]$/      (if you want to allow brackets inside)
/^\[\[[^\]]*\]\]$/   (if you don't)
```

`^` an `$` are end of string anchors and let you test the whole string.

Comment: Why does OP "need this" ? What did you changed and why did you changed it? What was wrong with OP's code?

Comment: This matches nothing for me. Eg. no match in `aa[[bb]]cc dd`.

Comment: @marekful Type this in your console: `/\[\[[^\]]*\]\]/.test("[[aa[[bb]]cc dd]")`

Comment: The tag is PHP not JavaScript.

Comment: it allows more 3 brackets at the beggening, can you help me it must be only `[[anything]]`

Comment: @StreetCoder What do you mean ? What's exactly the requirement ? You must write down exactly the constraints. If you don't want a bracket before, you could add `(^|[^\]])` before for example.

Comment: at the begenning `[[` and at the end `]]` otherwise invalid.

Comment: Thanks @dystroy it must be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex

```
\[{2}[^\[\]]+\]{2}
```

try this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sA1pF2/1)

**Explanation**

1. `\[{2}` I want exactly `[[`
2. `\[{2}` I want exactly `]]`
3. `[^\[\]]+` I want anything that is not `[` or `]` repeated one or more times

and if you want to catch only between two brackets

```
(?<=[^\[]\[{2})[^\[\]]+(?=\]{2}(?!\]))
```

try this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sA1pF2/6)